# Create a .bib file with citation style

Tags: bibliographies

I created a BibTex file using Mendely **(Citation Style = Biomedical Signal Processing an Control)**, an example for an article is:

K. J. Friston, A. Mechelli, R. Turner, C. J. Price, Nonlinear responses
in fMRI: the Balloon model, Volterra kernels, and other hemodynamics,
NeuroImage 12 (4) (2000) 466-477.

but the space between for example (**K. space J.** in the name of the author) does not exist in Elsevier (Biomedical signal processing and control) published versions:

K.J. Friston, A. Mechelli, R. Turner, C.J. Price, Nonlinear responses
in fMRI: the Balloon model, Volterra kernels, and other hemodynamics,
NeuroImage 12 (4) (2000) 466-477.

[image]

How can I suppress this space in the .bib file?

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[3p]{elsarticle}
\begin{document}
Text \cite{Friston2000} text

\section*{References}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
\bibliography{librar}
\end{document}
```

**database entry**:

```
@article{Friston2000,
author = {Friston, K J and Mechelli, A and Turner, R and Price, C J},
journal = {NeuroImage},
number = {4},
pages = {466--477},
title = {{Nonlinear responses in fMRI: the Balloon model, Volterra kernels, and other hemodynamics}},
volume = {12},
year = {2000}
}
```

Comment: You do not suppress the space in the `.bib` file, you let your bibliography style suppress it for you. In order to help you with that we need to know what style you use. Please prepare an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) to tell us about that.

Comment: Please provide a complete minimal file including a bib entry. This will likely result in getting a useful answer more quickly. At this point, I'm not even 100% certain you are using LaTeX/BibTeX to produce the paper.

Comment: I have updated my question, and about the style, I used Mendeley (reference management software: view -> Citation Style -> Biomedical Signal Processing and Control).

Comment: If you write this paper for an Elsevier journal I would not worry too much. If you follow their guidelines and use their template/`.bst` file they will probably take care of everything else. I don't think it makes much sense to modify the `.bst` file.

Comment: Just for reference: https://www.elsevier.com/authors/author-schemas/latex-instructions says that 'Custom layout will be removed.' So it is fairly pointless to change things anyway.